# Transfer Minecraft world from console to console

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have been playing on my friend's world and made a lot of progress (both on ps5). I want to be able to play when he's offline too. So I am going to get a realms subscription, however I want to continue to play on his world.

Basically, is there a way for him to upload his world to my realms (I'll invite him to my realms ofc). If not is there a way for him to send me his local world, which I can then download and upload to my realms?

Comment: does PS5 have the "export world" option? then maybe you can export it onto a USB stick and import it into your PS5?

Comment: i dont know, could try